# INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY in Genymotion

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, google-places-api, genymotion

I am developing one small application in android which is based on detecting user location and displaying places around him.

I developed app but now i want to try it in Genymotion emulator.

I found that Genymotion emulator is already installed Google API and i also installed com.android.vending.apk and com.google.android.gms.apk.

But still when i am trying to install my application it says that INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY.

I don't know why its happening?

Comment: Did you find any solution? Post it as an answer to help others like me. :)

Comment: Sorry i found no answer still facing same problem.

Comment: In this topic You can find easier solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/20636388/1467596

Comment: the answer is there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20635134/genymotion-emulator-installation-error-install-failed-missing-shared-library