# Genymotion Emulator : Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY

Tags: android, genymotion

I have a project with V1 of Google Maps API. So i need the follow tag in my manifest

```
         <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

The problem is when i try to run on a Genymotion emulator. I received this error

```
        Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
```

When i remove the uses-library tag I can run my project but then i have other error in my activity that uses google maps api.

What can i do??

Thanks

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I believe they dropped the Google Apps option and you have to install it manually now with the  apk files from the following link. You can just drop them on the VM and they'll be installed.

### original source

[This is a good tutorial](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952). Check this link for the up to date location of these zipped files. *The links in the step by step below might be broken.*

### step by step

Just a quote of the required steps. *Check the previous link for up to date info in case these links are be broken.*

> 1) Download the following ZIPs:
>
> ARM Translation Installer Android 6.0 - https://mega.nz/#!p4lFlCZR!TFsb8dMqNdAJjKoCDPDDvNtcQdEB0-KkVlTgQVwG20s
>
> Download the correct GApps for your Android version:

UPDATED link for Google Apps for Android 4.3 is (the ones below are broken) https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=23060877490000124

*thanks to user @SAM for the update*

> Google Apps for Android 4.3 - http://goo.im/gapps/gapps-jb-20130813-signed.zip
>
> Google Apps for Android 4.2 - http://goo.im/gapps/gapps-jb-20130812-signed.zip
>
> Google Apps for Android 4.1 - http://goo.im/gapps/gapps-jb-20121011-signed.zip
>
> 2) Next Open your Genymotion VM and go to the Homescreen
>
> 3) Now Drag&Drop the Genymotion-ARM-Translation.zip onto the Genymotion VM window.
>
> 4) It
>   should say "File transfer in progress", once it asks you to flash it
>   click 'OK'
>
> 5) Now Reboot your VM using ADB or an app like ROM Toolbox. If
>   nescessary you can simply close the VM window, but I don't recommend
>   it.
>
> 6) Once you're on the Homescreen again Drag&Drop the
>   gapps-jb-20130813-signed.zip(or whatever version you got) onto your
>   VM, and click 'OK' when asked
>
> 7) Once it finishes, again Reboot your VM
>   and open the Google Play Store. Sign in using your Google account
>
> 8) Once
>   in the Store go to the 'My Apps' menu and let everything update(fixes
>   a lot of issues)
>
> 9) Now try searching for 'Netflix' and 'Google Drive'
>
> 10) If
>   both apps show up in the results and you're able to Download/Install
>   them, then congrats you now have ARM support and Google Play fully
>   setup!

Comment: Yeahhh just that!!! Google should buy Genymotion to improve the default emulator.

Comment: Or you could pay for the Genymotion license so they can hire developers to improve it...

Comment: when i transfer it to Virtual AVD then it just copying files to sdcard

Comment: ARM Translation Installer v1.1 link is broken

Comment: @wmora check original topic at XDA here http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952 it should have links and even an attached zip.

Comment: I was not able to complete steps 8-10 'cause internet connection isn't available on free Genymotion devices, but anyway after step #7 everything worked fine, cheers!

Comment: @bgplaya you can set up network on your genymotion for personal use. I configure that using virtual box. Involves creating a host only network adapter in the general virtual box preferences and linking that in the image specific settings. All within the network tabs. I use adapter 1 host only and adapter 2 NAT.

Comment: oh, cool, thanks! Genymotion is nice when trying to show results sharing screen during online presentations: dawn fast)

Comment: Google Apps for Android 5.0: https://www.androidfilehost.com/?w=file-thanks&fid=95784891001614559

Comment: I have Genymotion 2.6 for personal use. I tried dragging and dropping the .zip files you've mentioned and it didn't work for me. I got the "File transfer in progress" dialog, but nothing else. It didn't ask me to "flash" it, and I'm not sure what that means. I'm trying to run a VM with Android KitKat 4.4.4. Any pointers?

Comment: I works like a charm but I am going to share updated links.

Comment: @SAM I've updated the link in this answer. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

In the upper right corner of the Genymotion emulator, there is an Open GAPPS button above the battery option. Clicking that will prompt you to install Open GAPPS.

Once it's installed and the emulator is rebooted, you can install your app.

Answer (score 0):

Go with @hcpl answer.
I am only updating links to required libraries.

1) Download the following ZIPs:
ARM Translation Installer Android 6.0 - 
https://mega.nz/#!p4lFlCZR!TFsb8dMqNdAJjKoCDPDDvNtcQdEB0-KkVlTgQVwG20s

2) Download the correct GApps for your Android version:
Google Apps for Android 4.3 - 
https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=23060877490000124

Kindly let me know in case of issue.